# I need to pass an env variable to docker through ssh from gitlab-ci

Tags: bash, docker, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

From my gitlab-ci I would need to pass an environment variable with the spring profiles to docker compose. Such variable is defined for each server environment where we deploy.

So, in my gitlab-ci I have this:

```
.deploy_template: &deploy_template
  script:
    - echo $ENV_SPRING_PROFILES
    # start containers
    - $SSH_COMMAND user@$CI_ENVIRONMENT_URL "cd $REMOTE_DEPLOY_DIR/docker && SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILES=$ENV_SPRING_PROFILES && DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375 && docker-compose up -d"


deploy_811AC:
  <<: *deploy_template
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  only:
    - /^feature.*$/
    - /^fix.*$/
  environment:
    name: ccvli-ecp626
    url: 10.135.XXX.XXX
  variables:
    ENV_SPRING_PROFILES: "mock"
```

When I run the runner, I can see with this - echo $ENV_SPRING_PROFILES the value of the variable. However, it seems not be replaced in the SSH command as docker-compose say the variable SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILES is empty.

It is becoming a kind of nightmare so any clue is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have not to much experience with gitlab ci, but what I think is that the way variables are "declared" is not with "=" but like this:

```
variables:
    SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILES: $SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILES 

script:
    ...
    - $SSH_COMMAND user@$CI_ENVIRONMENT_URL "cd $REMOTE_DEPLOY_DIR/docker && $ENV_SPRING_PROFILES && DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375 && docker-compose up -d"
```

Once it is declare on the first block, you can start using it on the code :)

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the answer but no, they are different things.
The first variable that I declare, is a gitlab variable that will contain a value.

The second declaration will become a unix environment variable key in the server where I am deploying and therefore I would need to pass to such variable, the value I declared first in the gitlab variable (is the dynamic value that depends on the environment where I am deploying on.